# How to solve USB error at start up?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, usb, usb-modem

In my laptop I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS
I have the dual  boot option with Windows 8.

When I power on my laptop and after selecting ubuntu, every time it shows an error message.

```
[  22.174038] usb 1-1.6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

But after sometimes laptops normally works.But sometimes I have an issue with connecting my usb modem(dongle) too. Is there any relation with this error and connecting error of dongle.?
How to solve the mentioned error ?

Comment: Can you use `lsusb` in terminal to discover the identity of 1-1.6? Another way is to leave the dongle disconnected when you boot, and see if the error goes away. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to one [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110#comment59659668_13661508) on Stack Overflow there are files which contain an explanation of the error code number.

```
$ find /usr/include/ -iname *errno* -print -exec grep 110 {} \;
…
/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
#define ETIMEDOUT   110 /* Connection timed out */
```

My interpretation in this case would be that the usb subsystem tried to detect and read the device descriptor of device 1-1.6 to know how to communicate with this device. Unfortunately the device didn't answer in time so the connection timed out at 22.174038 in this example. The OS can make one or more attempts to detect the device after this failure, please check `journalctl` (search works like in vim) after the event happened, was it detected correctly after another attempt by the OS shortly after? Was it the modem dongle or something else?

If it got detected then there is not much to worry about. If it didn't then you need to identify to which device this problem relates to and when it happens. Does it also happen when you switch from Windows to Ubuntu or when you reboot Ubuntu?

To avoid problems with USB Internet dongles I recommend to use the SIM card it contains in a mobile wifi hotspot, a Dual SIM phone with hotspot functionality or an internal modem instead.

The question I linked to earlier was answered by the OP himself, he said that updating the firmware/BIOS solved the issue for him. You can check if there is a firmware update for your laptop available or for the USB device in question (usually not, but possible).

Comment: +1 for nifty command `find /usr/include/ -iname *errno* -print -exec grep 110 {} \;`